# C++ linker options for RPATH of linked library

Tags: c++, linker, dependencies, ld, rpath

I have a MyApp project which is dependent of `lib1.so` library. `lib1.so` has own dependency `lib2.so`:

```
MyApp -> lib1.so -> lib2.so
```

I want to run MyApp with all dependencies in one directory.
For `lib1.so` the solution is `-rpath` key in linker options:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'")
```

But it does not work for `lib2.so` - the application does not find it.
It seems `lib1.so` do not use rpath of application.
Is there any way to specify rpath for `lib1.so`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to specify rpath for `lib1.so?`

A couple of options are available:

1. Link `MyApp` with both `lib2.so` and `lib1.so`, so that it loads `lib2.so` using `MyApp`'s rpath before loading `lib1.so`.
2. `patchelf --set-rpath '$ORIGIN' lib1.so` to make `lib1.so` use `$ORIGIN` when looking for `lib2.so`.